# What are the best parameters of LED lights for Phalaenopsis orchids

Tags: indoors, light, orchids, led

I am planning to use LED lights for growing Phalaenopsis orchids. What are the parameters I should choose in terms of

- light strength
- color
- duration?

There is very minimal sunlight, if any at all.